# Select method of sheets class failed when trying to hide sheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am struggling with hiding sheets.

I used two sets of code:

```
 Sub hidesheets()
 Sheets("Materials - Specifications").Visible = False
 Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet").Visible = False
 End Sub
```

And next

```
Sub RAtoPDF()
Call hidesheets
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet 
Dim ArraySheets() As String
Dim custom_name As String
Dim x As Variant
        
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 33 Then
        'Sheets("Materials - Specifications").Visible = False
        ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)
        ArraySheets(x) = sh.Name
        x = x + 1
    End If
        
Next sh

Sheets(ArraySheets).Select

custom_name = "RA_" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                                ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & custom_name, _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
                                
Sheets("Frontsheet").Select
End Sub
```

I get:

> Select method of sheets class failed

with debugger pointing to:

```
Sheets(ArraySheets).Select
```

I tried this line without an external macro, but the error is the same.

The `XlVeryhidden` option also is not working.

Comment: Are you trying to select sheets that are hidden?

Comment: When you cycle through the sheets it will include hidden sheets, but you can't select hidden sheets. Check your `ArraySheets` elements when the debugger halts on that line. `View > Locals Window`

Comment: I would like to deselect the sheets which I don't need to. I used the hidden option, because I though that the code will omit them.

Comment: You should just create a list of sheets you want to exclude and check against that when adding to your `ArraySheets`

Comment: I think it may be a syntax error - I believe you need to use `Sheets(ArraySheets()).Select` so that it properly references the Array. In the future, using Option Explicit at the top of your code will help catch that

Comment: I already have Option Explicit. I can't use Sheets(ArraySheets()).Select because this document is to be expanded and new sheets will be added. Only these 2 which I mentioned are fixed and won't be copied. I must have the solution to the exclusion or deselect these 2 sheets particularly. It can be deselected instead.

Comment: What's the tab color for the two hidden sheets?  You don't really say *why* your're hiding them or whether those are the sheets you want to exclude...  Might help to be a bit more explicit in your question.

Comment: The tab color is 33. I want these sheets to be excluded if I can't hide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Select method of sheets class failed*** means that you select a hidden sheet for printing

```
If sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 33 And sh.Visible = True Then
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.